Cannot inject newline characters into input field using Nodriver
I am using Python to automate interactions with a web application. My goal is to send newline characters into an input field to separate domain names, but all attempts have failed to properly input newlines. Instead, trying different methods has either resulted in no action or has deleted the existing input.
Environment:

Python 3.x
Nodriver library

Here is a snippet of the function I am using to send text to an input field:
# Find the specific div element and fill it with domain names
editable_div = await tab.select('div[contenteditable="true"][role="textbox"]')
if (editable_div):
    await editable_div.click()  # Focus on the div
    for domain in domains:
        await editable_div.send_keys(domain)
        await editable_div.send_keys("\n")  # Send newline character

I have tried sending "\n", "\r\n", and even just "\r", but none have resulted in a newline:
Symptoms:

Sending "\r\n" clears the input field.
Sending "\n" seems to have no effect.

How can I correctly send newline characters to an input field in a web application using Python and the Nodriver library?
The input field accepts the newline when manually pressing enter key.
semrush.com/batch

maybe this input doesn't allow for new line. Better show url for this page. Put it in question, not in comments - it will be more visible and more people may see it and help.

did you tried to send it as one string - "\n".join(domains) ?

"\n".join(domains) did not work and The input field accepts the newline when manually pressing enter key.

maybe key enter sends different code - or maybe javascript catch enter and it add new line to input field. We can't see URL so we can't test it.

https://www.semrush.com/batch/

you could add this in question - more people may see it so more people may help.

this page doesn't use standard <input> but some <div> with <span> - and it adds new <div> when I add domain and press enter. It may use JavaScript to detect key press.  And key event may use different code for ENTER

I tested it with undetected_chromedriver and works send_keys("\n") and send_keys(Keys.ENTER). So there is some problem in nodriver. Maybe you should send this problem to author of nodriver (he also created undetected_chromedriver)

I see, well I tried tagging him @ultrafunkamsterdam here but don't know how https://stackexchange.com/users/9088851/ultrafunkamsterdam  There's no email on his profiles

you would have to visit nodriver on GItHub and create issue on https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/nodriver/issues. But I think I found solution using JavaScript. I will create answer soon.

It seems send_keys() in nodriver has problem with this page but send_keys() in undetected_chromedriver (created by the same author) works correctly.
But it works when I use JavaScript to send KeyboardEvent with keyCode: 13 and with bubbles: true
js_function = "(item) => { item.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {keyCode: 13, bubbles: true})); }"

await editable_div.apply(js_function)

and maybe the whole point is in bubble because this element on page is not standard textbox but <div> with nested <span> for every domain - and maybe it has to send this event to parent element which catches it and it replaces Enter with new <span> (with next domain) inside <div>

Full working code
import asyncio
import nodriver as uc

async def main():
    domains = ['A.com', 'B.com', 'C.com']

    browser = await uc.start()

    page = await browser.get('https://www.semrush.com/batch/')
    await page.maximize()

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    
    editable_div = await page.select('div[contenteditable="true"][role="textbox"]')
    
    if (editable_div):
        await editable_div.click()
        
        # js_function = """() => { document.querySelector('div[role="textbox"]').dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter', which: 13, keyCode: 13, bubbles: true, cancelable: true})); }"""
    
        js_function = "(item) => { item.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {keyCode: 13, bubbles: true})); }"
        
        for domain in domains:
            await editable_div.send_keys(domain)
            #await editable_div.send_keys('\n')
            #from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
            #await editable_div.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            await editable_div.apply(js_function)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(main())

    input("Press ENTER to close")


So tricky! thank you, marked as solved.
